# How to parse dynamic json reponse and get specific value and pass it as an input to next request

Tags: json, scala, gatling, katalon-studio

I get .json file as a response from an API and from that file I should parse and fins specific parameter and pass it as an input to the next request, how do I do that using Katalon.

If I say

```
response = JSON.parse("response.json");
```

it says it is unable to identify JSON as valid. Can someone help me out with the solution?

Comment: I'd really look for any other way to do this - is the parameter you're trying to retrieve able to be determined via any other way?

Comment: My response json looks like below , from there i should extract time slip number:

Comment: {"responseStatusCode":"OK""data":{"screenName":"employeeTimeslip","screenType":"Redirect","searchResultCount":0,"rows":[],"tabs":[],"searchParams":{"employeeID":"000092926","timeslipNumber":"201900019701"}

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON *is* invalid, maybe it is a copy-paste issue.

The valid JSON should be

```
{
  "responseStatusCode": "OK",
  "data": {
    "screenName": "employeeTimeslip",
    "screenType": "Redirect",
    "searchResultCount": 0,
    "rows": [],
    "tabs": [],
    "searchParams": {
      "employeeID": "000092926",
      "timeslipNumber": "201900019701"
    }
  }
}
```

So, you were missing a "," between "OK" and "data" and two closing curly braces at the end of the file.

You can check JSON files for validity yourself using online JSON validators, for example, [this one](https://jsonformatter.org).

Comment: thats true, it was typo.. thanks for the comment.  I found a solution

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to read specific parameter from the json response file like below:

val scn = scenario("ClaimSubmission")

.exec(http("request_2")
            .post("URL")
            .headers(headers_2)
            .body(RawFileBody("json file path"))
.check(jsonPath("$..timeslipnumber").find.saveAs("timeslipnumber")))

Timeslip number would be retrieved using : .check(jsonPath("$..timeslipnumber").find.saveAs("timeslipnumber")))